# Probability involving the maximum of i.i.d. uniform r.v.'s

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

**The question is** :

> $100$ numbers are independently and uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.Then what is the probability that the maximum of these numbers will be at most $0.9$?

How can I solve it? Please give me a hint. Then I will retry it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $$\max_i U_i \leqslant t \iff U_i\leqslant t\ \forall i$$

Comment: Also, the probability that any continuous random variable takes a specific value is zero.

Comment: I assume these $100$ numbers are not only uniformly distributed, but also mutually independent?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "that the maximum of these numbers will be $at$ $least$ $0.9$*?

Comment: @IanMiller I read it as "at most," but in any case either will do by the same method...

Comment: Yeah Clement C you have rightly understood what I have tried to say.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. I have edited your question to reflect this; please, check it is indeed what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In this answer, I made the (natural) assumption that the 100 random variable are not only identically distributed, but also independent.*

**Hint:** look at the cumulative distribution function of $X\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \max_{1\leq k\leq n} X_k$ ($n=100$ here), and use independence of the $X_k$'s to factor.  (Spoiler below.)

**Spoiler #1**

> $X \leq x$ iff $X_k \leq x$ for all $k$.

**Spoiler #2**

> By definition (and then independence) of the $X_k\sim\mathrm{U}(0,1)$, $$\begin{align}F_X(0.9) &= \mathbb{P}\{X \leq 0.9\} = \mathbb{P}\{\forall k, X_k \leq 0.9\} = \prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb{P}\{X_k \leq 0.9\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_1 \leq 0.9\}^n\\&= 0.9^n\end{align}$$